# Адаптивная вёрстка - определение мобильными устройствами ширины сайта?

Tags: css, css3, адаптивная-верстка, media-queries

Переверстали портал повсеместно flex-боксами. Выбрали минимальню ширину 490px - прописав следущее:

```
html {
    min-width: 490px;
}
body
{
    overflow-x: hidden;
    min-width: 490px;
}
```

При ресайзе окна браузера на компьютере мышкой - получаем ожидаемое, страницы скукоживаются. Открыв на мобильном устройстве портал - видим практически то-же отображение, что и полноэкранное отображение на комьютере - сжимания не происходит. Мобильный браузер сам определяет оптимальную ширину страницы.

**Вопрос**: как подсказать мобильному браузеру, что страницу нужно сжимать до предела min-width, оценивая собственный размер экрана? Желаемое: ширина 640 - жмёт ширину до 640, ширина 320 - жмёт ширину до min-width .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Учитывая, что минимальная ширина должна оставаться на уровне 490px, то при открытии на устройствах меньшей ширины - окно должно корректно масштабироваться. Для этого:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

**Внимание** - без initial-scale. Иначе пользователю самому придётся скалить. Минимальную ширину - эти 490px желательно прописать жёстко,  помощью скрипта в мета-тег. Если используется jQuery - то таким образом:

```
var viewportOriginalContent = null;
var adaptiveSetMin = function()
{
    if (!viewportOriginalContent) viewportOriginalContent = jQuery('meta[name=viewport]').attr('content');
    if(window.innerWidth <= 490) {
        jQuery('meta[name=viewport]').attr('content', 'width=490');
    }else{
        jQuery('meta[name=viewport]').attr('content', viewportOriginalContent);
    }
};
jQuery(document).ready(adaptiveSetMin);
jQuery(window).resize(adaptiveSetMin);
```

Answer (score 2):

Возможно в head отсутствует `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Answer (score 0):

```
@media screen and (min-width: 490px){
    html {
        width: 490px;
    }
    body
    {
        overflow-x: hidden;
        width: 490px;
    }
}
```

вроде бы так, ну и в head

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: Не совсем так, если цель не сделать 2 вариации ширины (фуллскрин и 490px) , а сделать растягивание вёрстки от 490px до бесконечности.

Comment: ну здесь и нету никаких вариаций, именно 490 ++

Comment: я вижу тут дословно перевод css - при ширине экрана от 490px ширина body и html = 490px

Comment: хм, м.б. я не понял, что имеется ввиду..
можно так сделать, правда ни разу на практике не встречал
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=490, initial-scale=1">`